# knockout deferred evaluation

Tags: binding, knockout.js

Consider the following code:

```
 self.IsVisible = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
             //some logic goes here
            }

            return true;
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    }, this);
```

My problem, is that despite the deferEvaluation option being set to true, the code in IsVisible is reached when I first create my viewModel. I would like this code to be only accessed when the IsVisible binding is actually done somewhere....

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How do you know that the read function is being executed? Have you put an alert in there?

Comment: a breakpoint in chrome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a jsFiddle to look at, I've [created one](http://jsfiddle.net/manzanotti/gPs5c/2/), and it works exactly as I'd expect it to in IE9, and it appears to work in Chrome. Are you absolutely sure that `applyBindings` isn't is the call stack when you hit your breakpoint in Chrome?

Comment: I had missed the fact that the binding occurs when applyBindings is called.... duh... thanks for that.